# Status code 200, но cors error

Tags: reactjs, angular, axios, cors

Делаю запрос на получение картинки, в header ничего не пишу, делаю запрос через axios.get, только ставлю responseType: blob, чтобы потом скачать картинку. На линукс скачивает, на винде и маке нет. Если отключить cors через плагин - скачивает и на винде, я уже немного запутался, вдруг кто - то знает, что именно нужно сделать
Сайт написан на angular + react (пока что)
Возможно еще что - то нужно будет, но я не знаю, что именно еще нужно скинуть

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: сервер должен возвращать заголовок ...allow-origin: *

Comment: @ArchDemon , да, спасибо, я вот сейчас гуглю и тоже пришел к этому варианту